# Unsupported JOIN condition in Clickhouse, how can I make an equivalent query?

Tags: sql, left-join, clickhouse

what can I do about this type of queries in Clickhouse which use >,<,<=,>= and BETWEEN in join ON conditions?

```
SELECT
    created_at AS date,
    count(DISTINCT P.uid) / count(DISTINCT S.uid) * 100 AS conv_by_install_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    uid,
                    min(created_at) AS created_at
                FROM
                    states
                WHERE
                GROUP BY
                    uid
            ) S0
    ) S
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            uid,
            min(created_at) AS pay_time
        FROM
            payment
        WHERE
            count = 0
        GROUP BY
            uid
    ) P ON S.uid = P.uid AND datediff('day', S.created_at, P.pay_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 3 --this is the problem
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

it throws an error I could not have solved for a long time:

```
DB::Exception: Unsupported JOIN ON conditions. Unexpected 'dateDiff('day', created_at, pay_time) >= 0': While processing dateDiff('day', created_at, pay_time) >= 0. (INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION)
```

From documentation I know that Clickhosue doesn't support >,<,>=,<= JOIN conditions but how can I work around that and make an equivalent query using LEFT JOIN?

tried many other queries but didn't come up with an equivalent one when using LEFT JOIN

Comment: You can use WHERE (with the 'datediff between' condition) after the JOIN; this will be equivalent but will consume more RAM, as it produces a bigger cartesian product.

Comment: Do a regular INNER JOIN, put datediff condition in the WHERE clause if required. UNION ALL select from s where not exist matching p.

Comment: didn't work, I will add to this post when I solve it